# How do i add in vertex on the surface area?

Tags: modeling

[image: Here's the pic]

I control right click but it sets where my cursor at instead of my model surface area. Is there anyway to add vertex points without the need to use edge?

Comment: Did you try enabling the SNAP (to plane) feature?

Comment: Sorry, could you be a bit more specific as to what you're trying to do? Are you simply trying to add a vertex to a face?